# What is the proper way to log manual SQL statements with active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pg

I am doing a raw sql query with PG exec_params:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.exec_params(...)
```

When this query is executed, there is no friendly SQL logging happening.  Is there a preferred way to get that to happen so I can actually see what is executed, similar to when I do a regular query via the active record api?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out with

```rb
  create_table :tasks do |t|
    t.boolean :a, default: false
    t.boolean :b, default: false
    t.boolean :c, default: false
    t.string :d
    t.string :e
  end

  class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.test_sql
      random_bool = [true, false]
      sql = "insert into tasks (a, b, c, d, e) values ('0', '0', '0', ''1', 'I just dont know')"
      row_count = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.exec_params(sql)
    end
  end

Task.test_sql  # => #<PG::Result:0x00007faeef4461c8 status=PGRES_COMMAND_OK ntuples=0 nfields=0 cmd_tuples=1>
Task.last      # => #<Task id: 1, a: false, b: false, c: false, d: "1", e: "I just dont know">

# here is the logs
# >> D, [2020-03-04T11:21:12.977892 #17467] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
# >> D, [2020-03-04T11:21:12.981050 #17467] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
# >> D, [2020-03-04T11:21:12.981931 #17467] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "key"  [["key", "environment"], ["value", "default_env"], ["created_at", "2020-03-04 10:21:12.981267"], ["updated_at", "2020-03-04 10:21:12.981267"]]
# >> D, [2020-03-04T11:21:12.982333 #17467] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  COMMIT
# >> W, [2020-03-04T11:21:12.985424 #17467]  WARN -- : Creating scope :system. Overwriting existing method TaskStatus.system.
# >> D, [2020-03-04T11:21:12.991951 #17467] DEBUG -- :   Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" ORDER BY "tasks"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what the problem is you want to get solved.